# Laravel - Correct usage of URL::route() function in extended blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm extending a blade layout in Laravel. In master page, I defined a html form, and I want set action url of form in child page.

Master:

```
@section('left')
<form method="post" action="@yield('action')">
    @show
</form>
```

Child:

```
@section('left')
    @parent
    @section('action', "{{ URL::route('contact') }}")
    <button name="ok" class="btn-link">register</button>
@stop
```

with this code, form action sets as below:

```
<form action="<?php echo e(URL::route('contact')); ?>" method="post">
    <button class="btn-link" name="ok">register</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@section('action', URL::route('contact'))
```